# Piping in PowerShell: Connot bind argument to parameter <parameter> because it is null

Tags: windows, powershell

I have been practicing PowerShell by dealing with some of the tasks I could do in the file explorer.  I am organizing some files for a python project which I am doing.  My goal was to copy all python files in the current directory into the "V0.0_noProgressBar" directory:

```
ls -Filter "*.py" | copy $_ "V0.0_noProgressBar"
```

but it fails:

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At line:1 char:26
+ ls -filter "*.py" | copy $_ "V0.0_noProgressBar"
+                          ~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException 
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,
  Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

I assume this should be sufficient information to figure this out, let me know if more is needed. I have run into similar issues a number of times, so there must be a fundamental problem with my understanding of the placeholder `$_`.

Answer (score 2):

This can be simplified to:

```
Copy-Item *.py V0.0_noProgressBar
```

To answer original question, why `$_` is not working:

`$_` is only valid in script contexts, not just anywhere in the pipeline. E. g. you could use it in a script block of `ForEach-Object`:

```
Get-ChildItem -filter "*.py" | ForEach-Object { Copy-Item $_ "V0.0_noProgressBar" }
```

Comment: Thank you! Great answer.

Comment: Ensure you are practicing/learning using accepted best practices. Alias is a thing for interactive Powershell stuff, but not shared or production scripts/functions/modules. PSScriptAnalyzer settings, in PowerShell, VSCode, Visual Studio, will call them out as errors until you use the fill name. Each of those tools has settings to automatically expand the ones it knows about. Custom aliases, you need to remember to expand yourself. [Powershell Alias Best Practice](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+alias+best+practice%27&t=h_&ia=web). See all other PowerShell best practices as well.

Comment: @postanote Good point. In my own code, I never use aliases. I had based my answer on OPs code for demonstration purposes. For future readers the full form will be easier to look up, so I've now replaced the aliases.

Answer (score 1):

To augment [zett42's succinct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66401550/4749264). `$_` makes an appearance in several areas of PowerShell. Some cmdlets allow it's use in a script block the output of which is treated as the argument to the parameter.  In keeping with the question the `*-Item` cmdlets can make use of `$_`.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.txt" | Copy-Item -Destination { "C:\"+ $_.Name }
```

Obviously that's just an example. Perhaps a more useful case is `Rename-Item -NewName { ... $_ ... }`. `-NewName` which also works this way.

Other common cmdlets that make use of `$_` are `Select-Object`, `Sort-Object`, & `Group-Object`.  Overlapping some of these `$_` is used by many cmdlets to help define [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.1).  I strongly recommend reading this about topic. Along with the use of `$_` calculated properties are extremely useful.  I use them with `Select-Object` everyday!

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to pass a collection of files through a pipeline,
you can do this:

```
ls -Filter *.py | Copy-Item -Destination  "V0.0-NoProgressBar"
```

Here the Copy-Item cmdlet has no -Path parameter, so it gets the files from the pipeline.  See Help Copy-Item -full  to see that the -Path parameter can accept pipeline input.

This is not as simple as answers already given,  but it does show an alternative to trying to use $_ in a context where it is unavailable.